# How two average values of two pandas dataframes, but only if both cells are available?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "b": [0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "c": [0.5,0.5,0.5]
}, index = ["a", "b", "c"])
df1
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [0.3,0.3],
    "b": [0.3,0.3],
}, index = ["a", "b"])
df2
```

[image]

`df2` is always a subset of `df1`.

I want to calculate a weighted average between both if `df2` also contains the cell of `df1` (same index and column). If not, the value of `df1` should remain.

I can do this like this:

```
average = pd.DataFrame()

for r in df1.columns:
    for c in df1.columns:
        try:
            average.loc[r, c] = 0.4 * df1.loc[r, c] + 0.6 * df2.loc[r, c]
        except KeyError:
            average.loc[r, c] = df1.loc[r, c]
        
average
```

[image]

However, this takes quite a long time for bigger dataframes - is there a quicker way to do it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `fillna`:

```
(df1 * 0.4 + df2 * 0.6).fillna(df1)
```

Output:

```
      a     b    c
a  0.38  0.38  0.5
b  0.38  0.38  0.5
c  0.50  0.50  0.5
```

Comment: Nice! I like how pandas matches indexes and columns so that a subset with rows and columns `["a", "c"]` also works. Many thanks!